# How to make UITextField with limitation

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

1. phoneTextField;
2. emailTextField;

if i start to type in phoneTextField, emailTextField not allow character .
if the phoneTextField length will become 0 means then only emailTextField will allow character.

in the same as when start to type in emailTextField, phoneTextField not allow character.
if the emailTextFile length will become 0 means then only phoneTextField will allow character.

Please share the sample code..

Comment: Have you googled it?

Comment: i try but not come correctly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this delegate methods to perform this action

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if(textField == phoneTextFiled && (emailTextField.text.lenght == 0))
        return YES;

    else if(textField == emailTextField && (phoneTextFiled.text.lenght == 0))
        return YES;

    return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use textfield delegate

Set both of your textfields `delegate` to `self`

In `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` disable other textfield.

Then in `- textFieldDidEndEditing:` check the length of this textfield.If length ==0 ,set other textfield enabled

**Swift example**

I happen have two textfield named username and password. Just replace

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == usernameTextfield{
        passwordTextField.enabled = false
    }
    if textField == passwordTextField{
        usernameTextfield.enabled = false
    }
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    if count(textField.text)==0{
        if textField == usernameTextfield{
            passwordTextField.enabled = true
        }
        if textField == passwordTextField{
            usernameTextfield.enabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do think that,if you enable a textfield but user cannot type in anything. It is not user fridendly

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method of text file and change according to your requirement like Example below..

```
 - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        if (textField==self.txtNewPassword || (textField == self.txtReNewPassword))
        {
            NSString *updatedText = [[textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
            if (updatedText.length > CHARACTER_COUNT)
            {
                return NO;
            }
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things you will get desire output. Here `Enable` and `Desable` will satisfied your requirement.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *) textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (textField.tag == kTextFieldTagPassword && textField.text.length!=0)
        {
            emailTextField.enable = NO;

        }
        else{
            emailTextField.enable = YES;
        }

        if (textField.tag == kTextFieldTagEmail && textField.text.length!=0)
        {
            phoneTextField.enable = NO;

        }
        else{
            phoneTextField.enable = YES;
        }


    });


    return YES;
}
```

Hope this help you.